# Access PHP Variables in C With a Hash Table - Change in level of Indirection of Pointer

Tags: php, c++, c

I am referring Sara Golemon "Extending and Embedding PHP". I am confused regarding the following snippet

```
zval **fooval;    
if (zend_hash_find(EG(active_symbol_table), "foo", sizeof("foo"), (void**)&fooval) == SUCCESS)
```

Why is `&fooval`, which would evaluate to a `zval***`, cast to a `void**`  ?

Comment: A better question would be something like "Why would someone change a pointer's indirection level?"

Comment: @ColeJohnson since zend_hash is a "generic" container taking anything in, in this case a zval** ...

Comment: @Cole Johnson Agreed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is assigning a pointer to the value of a pointer to a pointer. It doesn't care what type of pointer it is assigning, just that it is getting a pointer. `void` more-or-less, then, means "generic".

I will admit that this is a gross over-simplification, but would be the same as having this in PHP:

```
function foo(stdClass $bar){
   // do something
}

class Bat extends stdClass{

}
$bat = new Bat();
foo((stdClass)$bat);
```

Comment: Thanks @cwallenpoole for _It doesn't care what type of pointer it is assigning_
I was under the assumption that you can't change the indirection level for a pointer.
Trying 

    int a = 5, *p1 = &a, **p2 = &p1;

    cout<<"&a = "<<&a<<endl<<
       "p1 = "<<(int*)p1<<endl<<
       "&p1 = "<<&p1<<endl<<
       "p2 = "<<p2<<endl<<" - - - - - - -- - - - -- - \n";

    p1 = (int *)&p2;

    cout<<"&a = "<<&a<<endl<<
       "p1 = "<<(int*)p1<<endl<<
       "&p1 = "<<&p1<<endl<<
       "p2 = "<<p2<<endl<<" - - - - - - -- - - - -- - \n";
 
helped.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion with changing Pointer Indirection Level can be explained using the following snippet.

In this case ipNew is single level pointer, but using (single or chain of )indirection operator you can use it to retrieve values until the value on right of '*' is an address

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

int i = 1;
int* ip = &i;
int** ipp = &ip;

cout<<"i = "<<i<<"\nip =  "<<ip<<"\nipp = "<<ipp<<"\n*ip = "<<(*ip)<<"\n**ipp = "<<(**ipp);

int * ipNew = (int *)&ip;
cout<<"\n\ni="<<i<<"\nip="<<ip<<"\nipp="<<ipp<<"\n"<<"*ip="<<(*ip)<<"\n**ipp="<<(**ipp)<<endl<<"\nipNew="<<ipNew<<"\n*ipNew="<<(int *)*ipNew<<"\n**ipNew="<<*((int*)*ipNew)<<endl;

return 0;
}
```